# Replace pandas Series with Series of different length but same indices

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose two pandas Series A and B:

A:

```
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    1
5    3
```

B:

```
3    4
4    4
5    2
```

A is larger than B and B has the same indices as A with different values. I'm trying to replace the values of A with those of B.

`A.replace(to_replace=B)` seems obvious but does not work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
C = B.combine_first(A).astype(int)
print (C)
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    4
5    2
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with more basic pandas operators.

```
a.loc[b.index.values]=b.values
```